# Prepared statements on Select statements

Tags: mysqli, prepared-statement

I’m just starting to convert all of my site’s code into prepared statements for that extra security cushion but I find myself running into the same questions.

After some reading, I’ve decided to use prepared statements on all select queries, however I’m not sure if all of variables in these queries require to be used as “parameters” in the prepared statement.

For example:

> 1. Where some_column IS NULL
> 2. Where some_column = $_SESSION[‘some-session-var’]
> 3. Where some_column IN ($someArray)

Also, is there some way to give each condition a “name” rather than using the question mark? I feel like I’ve seen this before in documentation, but I’ve had no luck finding it since.

For example: `Where city_name = :cityName`. If so, how would I go about binding the parameters here?

Thanks,

Evan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. All data going to the query should be added via placeholders. 
Otherwise there will be no security at all.

Though prepared statements extremely limited and support only scalar values, so, your first and third examples require extra coding (examples can be found in plenty under the tag)

Named placeholders you mentioned belongs to PDO, mysqli don't support them

Comment: For the NULL issue, it seems like this will do the trick:

$price = NULL; // NOTE: no quotes - using php NULL
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM product WHERE price <=> ?"); // Will select products where the price is null
$stmt->bind_param($price);

However, what should I do about the IN issue? A loop or sorts?